# How do I remove or disable the search box in windows explorer on Windows 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, citrix

I need a way to disable the search box from Windows Explorer. I've found a way to do this with the Start menu, but not in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

Programs and Features -> Turn Windows Features on and off -> Windows Search - uncheck that, reboot if requested, and it gets rid of the search box IIRC.

Comment: Man, right before I click "Post your answer" :)

Comment: I'll add that this solution can be applied to workstation versions of Windows as well, not only server editions.

Comment: Search is not installed. It is the Search Box in Windows Explorer 2008 R2.

Comment: How do you remove or disable search in the search box?